# Use exceptional char (minus) in property name of anonymous type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, anonymous-types

## The problem

I am trying to declare an anonymous type with a property named `data-maxchars`.

Because the minus is an operator it degrades (?) my desired property name into an operation and I get a compilation error: `Invalid anonymous type member declarator.`

I know I can escape reserved words using @, but I can't figure out if there is any way to escape the minus.

```
object attributes = (object)new { @class = "foo" } // OK
```

## The origin

The anonymous type is passed as an `object` argument to [TextAreaExtensions.TextArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505150.aspx): `<%= Html.TextArea(Model.Field.Id, val, rows, cols, attributes)%>`. This generates an input with the delivered attributes.

I want to use JS progressive enhancement to limit the number of chars the user can insert.
So I am using the `data-` prefix on my attribute: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

## Alternatives

- While writing this I noticed there is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470771.aspx) that takes an IDictionary instead of an object.
- I could write the input by hand.
- I could use a different prefix and ignore the standards. (Boo!)

But if there is a way to use the funny property name, I'd like to learn it.

Comment: I think you can achieve this with [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx), but it adds unnecessary overhead. So let's wait for gurus.

Comment: That was my thought too, but why would it make an unnecessary overhead?

Comment: @sternr: because the .NET [DLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx) is unfortunately much slower than the "statically"-defined classes. And besides that it makes more effort to use DLR classes (in comparison to the customary classes) in C#.

Comment: I might miss something, but identifiers in C# are simply not allowed to contain a minus... `private int data-maxchars; // <- invalid`

Comment: @Daniel: this is a limitation of C#, but probably not of the .NET runtime.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth Post as answer? *identifier* is a really helpful keyword for searching on this, thanks!

Comment: @Vlad: As long as he is writing C# code, it doesn't matter what is allowed when you write the IL code directly.

Comment: @Daniel: but maybe there exist some trick (similar to using @ in order to escape recognizing identifiers as reserved words), actually allowing what the OP wants?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Starting with ASP.NET MVC 3, you can use an underscore (`_`) instead, it will be automatically be replaced by a `-` for HTML generation. The magic is done in `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes`.

Eg:     `new { data_abc = "def" }` will be generated as `data-abc="def"`.

Comment: Seems not to work like that for me. Perhaps you have a different framework? (ASP.NET MVC here.)

Comment: Seems to be ASP.NET MVC 3 only. Tried it in MVC 2 and didn't get the same result. Edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: To give an example: HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(new { attr_a = "abc", attr_b = "def" })

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible at all, unless you generate your own classes via Reflection.Emit. But you will still have to pass some 'dictionary' for this, so you might as well go for that.

Using C# 3 collection initializers should make it look a lot better.

Comment: You mean `new Dictionary<string, object>(){ {"data-maxchars", 300} }`? I agree. Thanks, this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I might miss something, but identifiers in C# are simply not allowed to contain a minus...

```
private int data-maxchars; // <- invalid
```

Comment: I found this after your answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @ANeves: What is it that you find interesting there?

Comment: The thorough description of what is and what is not allowed, and where.

Comment: @ANeves That's correct. One can check a character with `char.GetUnicodeCategory` static method. The hyphen, minus, or dash `-` is a `DashPunctuation` corresponding to class `Pd` which is not allowed in the C# spec. The underscore `_` on the other hand is `ConnectorPunctuation`, class `Pc`, which is called _connecting-character_ in the C# spec and is allowed.